# Default Close Operation of a JFrame isn't working

Tags: java, swing, jframe, dispose

I'm using NetBeans.
My `JFrame` has as default close operation: `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`.
I have a button that is supposed to close the program on this `JFrame`, this is the action performed code:

```
private void bSalirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                       
    this.dispose();
}
```

I thought this would close **all** the `JFrame`s of the program but it doesn't, could you explain me why or how to fix it?

Comment: Does it do anything? Does it close one frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to exit your application with the button than you can use `System.exit()` or `frame.dispose()`.

but be careful with `System.exit()` as this will terminate the `JVM`.

So it is better to first confirm from user before this.
with `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog()`;

```
private void bSalirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){ 

        int exit = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                frame,
                "Are you sure you want to exit the application?",
                "Exit Application",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);                             
        if(JOptionPane.YES_OPTION == exit){
             frame.dispose(); // or System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Call [`frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29) when constructing the frame.  In the `actionPerformed` method, call [`frame.dispose()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29) & the JVM should end as long as there are no other non-daemon threads running.

`DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` can be seen in a short demo. on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7143398/418556).

[image]

> ..I thought this would close all the jFrames..

There should only be one (despite the above screen-shot, given it is an artificial situation).  See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)  The above demo will close after the 3rd frame is closed.

Comment: `setVisible` didn't work for me, but `dispose` did...interesting none the less

Comment: @MadProgrammer  I was wondering as to the correctness of `setVisible` as I wrote that.  To be honest, I usually rely on the `X` button or `F-4`. Now edited.

Comment: Agreed, never really had the OP's problem before

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Well, maybe the advice would have been better if there was an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) posted (like in the linked demo), but I even forgot to mention it before.  :P

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you called your JFrame *frame*, like this:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

You can close it by calling

```
frame.dispose();
```

Also, calling this.dispose() refers to the dispose() method that you defined in your class. This is probably why it isn't working. Do you have a method in your class that is called dispose? If so, what exactly does this method do?

Answer (score 2):

> EXIT_ON_CLOSE

That is what happens when you click the "X" button on the top right of the frame.

Your ActionListener is invoking dispose() on the current frame. If this is the only open frame then the application will also close, but the dispose method does not close all open frame/dialogs.

Check out [Closing an Application](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/). You can use the `ExitAction` for your button if you want to close the entire application since it will simulate a user clicking on the "X" button.

Answer (score 0):

I use below method, simply call this mesthod, it will close the current window/jFrame :

```
  private void close(){
    WindowEvent windowEventClosing = new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(windowEventClosing);     
}
```

Also set 'defaultCloseOperation' for **jFrame** in *properties*, according to your need.